# How to set document property details for excel sheet using pandas not workbook xlsxwritter?

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

1. need to set properties like author
2. the existed excel sheet to add properties, from workbook its leads to new excel and properties added but data is present which was extracted using pandas dataFrame.

3.https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_doc_properties.html

How to combine  pandas data frame and Workbook excel write sheets with one document file

the document need to save by the author: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7daXo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to set the author property of an xlsx file created from Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_author.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook = writer.book

workbook.set_properties({'author': 'Stack Overflow'})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me, which is similar to the above solution.

```py
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("randomfile.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df_row3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BOT", index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["BOT"]
workbook.set_properties({"author": "webscraping"})
workbook.close()
```